# Android After opening Application Background Service stops and new service starts

Tags: android, service

I have created a Service which starts when phone Boots up. But when I open Application the Service starts again and old-running service stops, but the service works. But when I close application this service stops either. How to use the service which started on boot and If Service which started on boot is killed by the system, how to re-run that service?

Here's my code

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" >
     <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
     </intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name=".AppMainService" />
```

MyBroadCastReceiver

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, AppMainService.class);
        context.startService(startServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

AppMainService

```
public class AppMainService extends IntentService {

    private Timer timer;
    private ReceiveMessagesTimerTask myTimerTask;
    public static AppPreferences _appPrefs;
    public static SQLiteDatabase qdb;
    public static Config config;
    public static Engine engine;

    /**
     * A constructor is required, and must call the super IntentService(String)
     * constructor with a name for the worker thread.
     */
    public AppMainService() {
        super("HelloIntentService");
    }
    public void onStart(Intent intent, Integer integer) {
        super.onStart(intent, integer);
    }
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        DB db = new DB(this);
        qdb = db.getReadableDatabase();

        _appPrefs = new AppPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        config = new Config();
        engine = new Engine();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, startId, startId);
        Log.i("sss", "Service sarted");
        return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
    }
    /**
     * The IntentService calls this method from the default worker thread with
     * the intent that started the service. When this method returns, IntentService
     * stops the service, as appropriate.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        timer = new Timer();
        myTimerTask = new ReceiveMessagesTimerTask();
        timer.schedule(myTimerTask, 0, 10000);
    }

    class ReceiveMessagesTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            //Sending messages
            Log.i("Service", String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())+_appPrefs.getToken());
        }
    }
}
```

And in My Activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AppMainService.class);
        startService(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is by design because you are subclassing `IntentService`. It automatically shuts down once it had processed all intents. If you want your service to persist, extend `Service` instead and implement your own threading mechanism.